# Customize Jetpack JSON API: How can I add more posts?

Tags: json, wordpress, jetpack

I'm using the Jetpack JSON API. At the moment I can get 20 posts through the JSON API. How can I get more then 20 posts? Can I change this by editing the Jetpack php files?

Comment: How are you making the API call?

Comment: https://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1/sites/[$site_url]/posts/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just [add `?number=100` to your request](https://developer.wordpress.com/docs/api/console/) <sup><sub>(max. 100)</sub></sup>:

[image]